# change upload path play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I am trying to change the saving path for images.
If I debug I see the following path:

```
 /tmp/playtemp4579361689183556686
```

I thought I will change the path with the directory with the command:

```
file.renameTo(new File(path))
```

Do some one know how I can change the path?
Where I did the mistake?

The whole code is below.

```
public Result doUpload() {

    Http.MultipartFormData<File> body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> picture = body.getFile("picture");

    Path uploadPath = environment.rootPath().toPath();

    final String uploadFolder = "/public/uploads/";

    if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType();
        File file = picture.getFile();
        String path = uploadPath + uploadFolder + fileName;

        Logger.info("path: {}", uploadPath);
        Logger.info("whole path: {}", path);

        file.renameTo(new File(path));

        return ok("File uploaded");
    } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return badRequest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `/tmp` (on applicable OS's) is a convention for compatibility since it's writable by all users and not just administrative users.

In my own upload projects I generally make a copy of the file into whatever path I want it and then delete the temporary file:-

```
Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get("/my/apps/file/store/path/", ("copy_" + name)), REPLACE_EXISTING)
Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

renameTo should actually do what you want.
I use it too in my project as you can see in this question:
[Play: How to prevent 404 on image src on first request after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425545/play-how-to-prevent-404-on-image-src-on-first-request-after-upload)

```
File movedFile = new File("/var/www/public/", "filename.jpg");
file.renameTo(movedFile);
```

That's how I use it. There shouldn't be a difference in the other Constructor is use. But from your question it isn't clear what is wrong on your side.

Also: note that moving a file to /public might not work on a production environment as you expect. When you do a production build everything in public is packaged in to a .jar file.
Files uploaded at runtime should be moved to an external location